# Ruby if vs end of the line if behave differently?

Tags: ruby

Why doesn't this code work?

```
b if b = true
```

Error: `` undefined local variable or method `b' ``

But this does:

```
if b = true
    b
end
```

Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: It can be even simplified: `k if k = 1` and `if k = 1; k; end`

Comment: This has been a slight annoyance of mine; I don't think there is any deep reason why your code can't work, so maybe they will add this feature in the next version of ruby.

Comment: Conditionals are expressions just like anything else in Ruby so this behavior is expected when the parser is looking to assign variables, and would be hard to change.  I do agree though that it is quite unintuitive and does not follow principle of least surprise.

Comment: As a matter of coding practice, I prefer to not see assignments in the condition. It makes maintenance of the code more difficult because it's hard to tell if an assignment was intended or a typo occurred and it should have been an equality test (`==`). The fact that it's not working as you expect would just be more cause to flag it in a code review.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a very good question.  It has to do with the scoping of variables in Ruby.

Here is a [post by Matz on the Ruby bug tracker](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1141) about this:

> local variable scope determined up to down, left to right.  So a local variable first assigned in the condition of if modifier is not effective in the left side if body.  It's a spec.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version as soon as `k` is hit, the parser pukes because it hasn't been seen yet.

In the second version, `k` is part of an assignment expression, and is parsed differently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason but the problem that the interpreter tries to lookup the variable `k` before evaluating the condition.

If you write it like this, there won't be any error and works as you expected:

```
k = nil
h = {k: 1}
v = k if k = h.delete(:k)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have put only one '='

Try with '=='

Then you will get error

In second example, you are assigning 'true' to b.

Answer (score 0):

*Because the Ruby interpreter creates a local variable when it sees an assignment*

In the second case, it hasn't yet seen the assignment, so the variable doesn't exist when the expression is parsed.

To be more precise, a method is first parsed into an internal representation, and then, perhaps, the code will eventually be called and actually executed.

Local variables are *created* in that parsing pass. It's a matter of declaration, it just means that the interpreter becomes aware of them. They won't be created in the sense of being given space or a value until the surrounding method is called by someone.